# Iterate JSON File Downloaded From S3

Tags: objective-c, swift, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to populate a table with the contents of a JSON file downloaded from S3 (using the AWS SDK).  I'm having difficulty looping through the `notifications` array because it doesn't seem to be an iterable object.  Nil is returned when typecasting the entire object to a dictionary.  I received an error stating that I cannot typecast the `notifications` String as an array.  How can I typecast the `notifications` object into something I can iterate?

```
//JSON file
{
   "notifications": [
       {
          "startDate": "2016-10-01 00:00:00",
          "endDate": "2016-10-31 23:59:59",
          "message": "October"
       },
       {
          "startDate": "2016-11-01 00:00:00",
          "endDate": "2016-11-31 23:59:59",
          "message": "November"
       }
   ]
}

//I omitted extraneous code
let task = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest)

if let output = task.result as? AWSS3GetObjectOutput{
    do{
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData((output.body! as? NSData)!, options: .AllowFragments)

        //Debug code that works
        print(json["notifications"]![0]) //Prints the first notification
        print(json["notifications"]![0]["startDate"])

        //Debug code that does not work
        let opt = json["notifications"] as! NSArray  //Can't typecast String as Array

        //A 'for' loop does not work as well.
    }catch{
        print("Error serializing JSON [\(error)]")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json["notifications"] as! NSArray` works *but* you have to first cast the result of NSJSONSerialization to the right type, in your case a dictionary:

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(json["notifications"] as! NSArray)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        print(json["notifications"] as! NSArray)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

Comment: While debugging this, I added `print(json["notifications"])` and received `NSCFArray length, unrecognized select sent to instance', but printing just json or json["notifications"][0]["startDate"] worked.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happened but it shouldn't happen again if you use only Swift objects (forget NS*).

Comment: I just realized I've answered in Swift 3 but the tag was just "swift"... oops.

Answer (score 0):

let opt = json["notifications"] as? Array  //Can't typecast String as Array

Please try this